# App crashes/stops constantly on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm trying to re-create the component to access a different data hosted on firebase.​ The app keeps stopping as soon as I launch it.

Error thrown: ​

FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.auth, PID: 3320 com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 5
                                                         detail: View tag:21
                                                          children(1): [
                                                        4,
                                                         ],
                                                          viewsToAdd(1): [
                                                        [1,5],
                                                         ],

Code used:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, Spinner, CardSection, AlbumDetail } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
    state = { loggedIn: null, albums: [] };

 componentWillMount() {
 firebase.initializeApp({
 apiKey: 'xx',
 authDomain: 'xx',
 databaseURL: 'xx',
 projectId: 'xx',
 storageBucket: 'xx',
 messagingSenderId: 'xx'
});

    axios.get('https://xx')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => 
            <AlbumDetail key={album.District} album={album} />);
    }

  renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return (
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        </CardSection>  
        );
      case false:
        return <LoginForm />;
      default:
        return <Spinner size='large' />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText='Authentication' />
        console.log(this.state.albums)
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

First change componentWillMount for componentDidMount. That it the recommended method to query network resources. Also, that makes sure that the component is mounted before you make any changes on it.

Second, remove the console.log from between the JSX, that does not work and is probably your main issue.

Third, don't assign the state like that. Use the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { loggedIn: null, albums: [] };
}
```